# make arraylist equal another arraylist java

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, copy

I have both 1d temporary arraylist and 2d original array list, I updated the temporary arraylist during a loop and at the end of the loop I need to make the original arraylist equal to the content of the temporary arraylist as follow:

```
while(!Front.get(front).isEmpty()){
        Q.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<Front.get(front).size();i++){
            if(!Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).isEmpty()){
                for(int j=0;j<Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).size();j++){
                    Individual_Number[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)]=Individual_Number[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)]-1;
                    if(Individual_Number[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)]==0){
                        Solutions_to_arrange[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)][Input.General_Inputs.Num_objectives+Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes]=front+1;
                        Q.add(Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        front++;
        Front.get(front)=Q // How to do this step
    }
```

I know there are methods like

```
Front.get(front) = new ArrayList<Object>(Q);
```

or

```
Front.get(front) = (ArrayList<Object>)Q.clone();
```

But Not sure if these methods are suitable since all this ways will give me a copy of my List, not all it's elements. So, if I change one of the elements in my copied List, it will be changed in my original List too.

Update
I proposed this solution any comment?

```
front++;
for(int i=0;i<Q.size();i++)
        Front.get(front).add(Q.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: How would you change a `Double`?

Comment: It won't change it... [Java is pass-by-value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

Comment: You're dealing with a problem in refusing to use objects / OOP. Don't just chuck everything into lists/collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work

```
while(!Front.get(front).isEmpty()){
        Q.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<Front.get(front).size();i++){
            if(!Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).isEmpty()){
                for(int j=0;j<Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).size();j++){
                    Individual_Number[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)]=Individual_Number[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)]-1;
                    if(Individual_Number[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)]==0){
                        Solutions_to_arrange[Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j)][Input.General_Inputs.Num_objectives+Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes]=front+1;
                        Q.add(Individual_Dominate.get(Front.get(front).get(i)).get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    front++;
        for(int i=0;i<Q.size();i++)
        Front.get(front).add(Q.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //supposedly you have ArrayList array = [1, 2, 3];

        for(int i : array) {
            array1.add(array.get(i));
        }

        System.out.print(array1);

        // output will give you [1, 2, 3]
```